# How to generate many passwords with kpcli?

Tags: password

Keepass has password generating function.

**Q:** How can I generate example: 400 000 passwords with kpcli to a text file?

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an answer, but using another tool: `pwgen`

```
user@host:~$ pwgen -s -c -1 -N 400000 15
```

Extracted from `pwgen` manuals:

> **-s, --secure**
>       Generate completely random, hard-to-memorize passwords. These should only be used for machine passwords, since otherwise it's almost
>   guaranteed that users will simply write the password on a piece of
>   paper taped to the monitor...
>
> **-c, --capitalize**
>       Include at least one capital letter in the password. This is the default if the standard output is a tty device.
>
> **-1**
>       Print the generated passwords one per line.
>
> **-N, --num-passwords=num**
>       Generate num passwords. This defaults to a screenful if passwords are printed by columns, and one password.

And the number at the end of the command, is how many characters long a password will be. You can add the `-y` option to add special characters to your generated passwords.

Cheers.