# Password list regenerate

Tags: linux

So I was learning some new ethical hacking techniques to test my password  and my family's  wifi security and possible vulnerabilities...

How would I write a code that would search for my password going from a - z and 1 - 9 including special characters until it finds the correct password.

I have some programming experience, I haven't been consistent with it to understand the power behind this type of code.

Comment: check this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183865/how-to-generate-many-passwords-with-kpcli

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking to brute-force a wifi password. I would suggest that rolling your own solution to this is, while no doubt educational, isn't your easiest solution. There are tools for this. If a search doesn't yield what you need, perhaps have a look at some answers at [InformationSecurity.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes but not a wifi password, "my" wifi, router, os passwords

Comment: You are trying to brute force passwords, this can be quite complicated, but there are tools, try checking out something like kali linux https://www.kali.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily write a function in c or java for example , but the files that will be generated will be huge .

I've put a simple loop to go from 1 to 1.000.000.000 and the output file was more then 10.5g  and it took 8 minutes,and it was only 10 numbers so having the 10 number + the 26 letters it's gonna be huge .

I recommend the use of kali linux to try other alternatives other then brute force , and if every thing failed try using this as a last recipe.

Note: generally all the isp routers are vulnerable, you can look for a vulnerability in your router in the network , and you can also use a powerfull linux distribution called WIFI SLAX.